# Bootstrap div and ul dont display correctly on small displays

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have footer on my website with five links in ul li floating left and register button floating right. I'm using twitter bootstrap btw. Problem starts when screen width gets too small. Button div doesn't properly go under ul element. I made jsfiddle so you get better idea what I mean.

http://jsfiddle.net/majlo182/ey6wd59j/1/

```
<footer id="footer">
    <div class="faq-links">
        <div class="container col-md-12">
            <ul class="col-md-8 pull-left">
                <li><a href="/content/link1" class="link">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/content/link2" class="link">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="/content/link3" class="link">Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="/content/link4" class="link">Link 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="/content/link5" class="link">Link 5</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <a href="/content/register" class="btn btn-add pull-right">Click here to <span>REGISTER</span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Any ideas how to make "register" display under all of the ul links when they don't fit next to each other?

Comment: You are misusing some Bootstrap classes there. `col-*` classes should only occur inside a `row` which in turn should only exist inside a `container` or `container-fluid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the correct bootstrap classes sometimes helps, even though I adjusted the CSS also a little bit

```
<footer id="footer">
    <div class="faq-links">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <ul class="list-inline pull-left">
                    <li><a href="/content/link1" class="link">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/content/link2" class="link">Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/content/link3" class="link">Link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/content/link4" class="link">Link 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/content/link5" class="link">Link 5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <a href="/content/register" class="btn btn-add pull-right">Click here to <span>REGISTER</span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Please check the result (with adjusted CSS) here: http://jsfiddle.net/koddistortion/31rkmmac/